# Как удалить элементы из списка?

Tags: python

Есть список -

```py
a = ['test1','test2','test3','test2','test5','test6','test7 ','testing8','test2','test10','test2']
```

И есть список -

```py
b = ['tet1','tet2','tet3','tet4','tet5','tet6','tet7','tet8','tet9','tet10','tet11',]
```

И переменная -

```py
c = 'test2'
```

Надо из списка `a` удалить все элементы которые не равны переменной `c`. То есть результат должен быть таким -

```py
a = ['','tet2','','tet2','','','','','tet2','','tet2']
```

А из списка `b` надо получить только те значения которые совпадают индексами со не пустыми значениями из списка `a`. То есть на выходе должно быть 2 переменные -

```py
a = ['','tet2','','tet2','','','','','tet2','','tet2']

b = ['','tet2','','tet4','','','','','tet9','','tet11']
```

Comment: Хорошо, а что у вас не получается?

Comment: Отформатируйте код

Answer (score 2):

```py
# проходим по всему списку и сравниваем каждый элемент с c, 
# если они равны, то оставляем, иначе заменяем пустой строкой
a = [i if i == c else '' for i in a] 

# проходим сразу по двум спискам и если элемент списка a - это пустая строка,
# то заменяем элемент списка b пустой строкой, иначе оставляем его
b = ['' if i == '' else j for i, j in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ок, изменил